# how to take cardinality from design to code?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table called products and a table called category and I want to say that each product must have at least 1 category and at most 2 category, so if I am right I will say that 1..N products ------ 1..2 category right ? and the most important issue here is how I make this cardinality ? do i make it in sql or i just make it in server code ( logic ) ? and do I need a joint table here or no ?

sorry if my question is bad but this issue is making my project no progress.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relational model and SQL standards would support this kind of requirement with a an assertion. But AFAIK, currently shipping SQL products don't support `CREATE ASSERTION`.

This kind of code will enforce the requirement that there be no more than two categories per product.

```
create table product_categories (
  product_code char(1) not null, -- references products (product_code), not shown
  category_num integer not null 
    default 1
    check (category_num in (1, 2)),
  category varchar(10) not null,
  primary key (product_code, category)
  );

insert into product_categories values
('a', 1, 'wire'),
('a', 2, 'cable'),
('b', 1, 'panel'),
('b', 2, 'plate');
```

It should be obvious that inserting any "category_num" besides 1 or 2 will raise an error. So each product code can have no more than two categories.

To enforce the constraint that each product must have at least one category, you'll need to write procedural code. Either triggers or stored procedures would work.

---

A discussion about adding declarative assertions to Oracle: [SQL Assertions / Declarative multi-row constraints](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028)

Comment: your answer is great but if i make it in code , for example if i make a query to check how many categories this product contains and if the output is 2 rows then i dont allow the product to have more and vice versa ... is this good or not effecient way ?

Comment: It's usually better to just insert, trap the error (if any), and take appropriate action. You have to trap errors anyway. There are a lot of things that can go wrong besides already having two rows. (I'd do that in a stored procedure, myself, and require all inserts and deletes to go through the stored procedure.)